# Is it possible to make Sql Server return empty fields instead of nothing when such fields don't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Think of this table:

```
 ____________
| ID | Value |
|  1 |  One  |
|  3 | Three |
```

If I run a query like this `SELECT Value FROM myTable WHERE ID = 1` I'm sure to get its appropiate value, be it `One` in this case, but if I change the `ID` to any other number non existant on that table, I will get nothing on the `Value` column, of course, since there wouldn't be any data there.

But is there a way to make Sql Server return at least an empty space when doing such queries?

Sql Fiddle with same case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f30f8/2

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f30f8/25

Answer (score 2):

```
select  Value
from    YourTable
where   ID = 1
union all
select  null
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable
        where   ID = 1
        )
```

So yes, it's technically possible, but you can see why this is much easier solved in a general purpose language.

Comment: I am trying this but it only seems to work when I select that one record that should be there specifically, I can't pick a range that would have that same specific record in between. Example, if I run the query with ID=2 it will give me nulls, but if I run the query with ID>=1 and ID<=3 it only returns the results for 1 and 3..

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can do this:

```
select coalesce(max(value), '')
from test t
where id = 1;
```

The idea is that `max()` always returns a value.  It will be `NULL` if there is no match, and you can replace that with an empty string (or whatever).

Comment: I'm trying this but I have a question, is max supposed to return ONLY 1 value? Because that's what I'm getting even when I run larger queries for more complete data sets, the idea is for this to work with such queries, not just 1 row like in the example, I probably should've explained it better.

Comment: I also tried just using `COALESCE` without the `MAX` but it never replaces the data that isn't there with what is supposed to replace it. Could it be because it needs to be `Null` rather than just not exist?

Comment: @user1676874 . . . I don't know what you mean by more complete data sets.  Your question is quite explicitly about one value.  I would suggest that you ask another question if you have a different set of data.  As for the `coalesce()` without the `max()`, that isn't going to work.