# How to Select records that don't exist in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This isn't about checking if a record exists before selecting it, or viceversa.

The issue is this, I have a database with many records, they are stored by date, by day to be specific, each day should have a set of values, but some days may not have any values at all, they may not exist. So when I try to do a query, I need to show all the data, even if it doesn't technically exist, it could show at least as a blank space but it should show.

Think of this table:

```
 ___________________________________
| id |    date    | value1 | value2 |
|  1 | 02/01/2014 |    1   |    1   |
|  2 | 02/03/2014 |    2   |    2   |
|  3 | 02/04/2014 |    3   |    3   |
|  4 | 02/06/2014 |    4   |    4   |
```

Now what the query needs to do is to return all the data that's in between a certain date range, say from `02/01/2014` to `02/03/2014`, it should return all the values between that date range, say:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date>=`02/01/2014` AND date<=`02/03/2014`
```

But that will only return this:

```
 ___________________________________
| id |    date    | value1 | value2 |
|  1 | 02/01/2014 |    1   |    1   |
|  2 | 02/03/2014 |    2   |    2   |
```

Now I know this is fairly obvious, it is selecting all the data that exists in the table given the range I sent to the query, but I'm working with a report that doesn't care if there were values for that given day or not, it must return every single day, even if there were records for that day or not, meaning that even if `02/02/2014` is not on the table, it has to be returned as well.

Sort of like this:

```
 ___________________________________
| id |    date    | value1 | value2 |
|  1 | 02/01/2014 |    1   |    1   |
|    | 02/02/2014 |        |        |
|  2 | 02/03/2014 |    2   |    2   |
```

It doesn't matter it has no data, it just can't leave the day as if it didn't happen.

I already tried using `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`, but since there are no values for those days, there are no null values either, so they simply just cannot replace `Null` with something else.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Comment: This is very similar to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683828/is-it-possible-to-make-sql-server-return-empty-fields-instead-of-nothing-when-su)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a recursive [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Something like this:

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime = '2/1/2014'
DECLARE @endDate datetime = '2/6/2014'

;WITH DateRange(RunningDate) AS
(
    SELECT @startDate AS RunningDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RunningDate + 1
    FROM DateRange
    WHERE RunningDate < @endDate
)

SELECT id, RunningDate date, value1, value2 
FROM DateRange LEFT JOIN myTable ON myTable.date = DateRange.RunningDate
```

*Edit...* IF you do go with this solution (take note of Aaron Bertrand's comment under my answer), note that you'll also have to specify the [max recursion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) if you intend on dealing with ranges greater than 3 months. The default is set to 100. This means that, as the query is currently written, it will only do a maximum of 101 dates (100 levels of recursion).

You can additionally specify `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` at the end of the last `SELECT` to overcome this. 0 means infinite levels of recursion. But again, take note of Aaron's post.

Comment: For three dates, this won't be too bad. But [the recursive CTE approach gets VERY expensive as the number of rows goes up](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3). A calendar table is a much more scalable approach.

Comment: @AaronBertrand +1 Good call. I'll have to check out that link.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
WITH
    -- Numbers CTE, courtesy Itzik Ben-Gan
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L4),
    -- Turn into Dates
  Dates AS(SELECT CAST('18991231' AS DATETIME)+n AS d FROM Nums)
SELECT * 
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN myTable t ON d.d = t.[date]
WHERE d.d>='02/01/2014' AND d.d<='02/03/2014'
```

Here is a version that is optimized for smaller date ranges:

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime = '2/1/2014'
DECLARE @endDate datetime = '2/3/2014'
DECLARE @days as INT = DATEDIFF(dd, @startDate, @enddate) + 1
;
WITH
    -- Numbers CTE, courtesy Itzik Ben-Gan
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  T4   AS(SELECT TOP (@days) 1 AS c FROM L4),
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS n FROM T4),
    -- Turn into Dates
  Dates AS(SELECT @startDate+n AS d FROM Nums)
SELECT * 
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN myTable t ON d.d = t.[date]
WHERE d.d>=@startDate AND d.d<=@endDate
```

Comment: Hmm, do you mind elaborating on this one? My tests are showing it to be far more intensive than the "bad" recursive CTE above. The execution plan is wicked. Am I missing something?

Comment: Define "far more intensive"  My tests show it to be very fast.  If you are relying on the query plans that is not reliable because they do not accurately estimate loops, cursors or recursive CTEs.  If you are truly concerned about it, there are other ways to construct the numbers/tally list that is more efficient for smaller numbers of days like you are using here.

Comment: Really I'm just trying to educate myself. I did observe it to be quite fast but at the same time, the query cost was 96% versus 4% for the recursive solution above. By no means am I suggesting that that solution is the end all. And perhaps my tests are flawed. I would just like to be better informed.

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time. I look forward to digging into this!

Comment: @Manny (correction: ) I have posted an improved version for shorter date ranges. As I noted above, query plans grossly underestimate loops and recursive CTEs because these are dependent on their implicit loop termination conditions which the T-SQL statistical optimizer is not at all designed to estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Fan had the right idea, but I thought it might help to see an implementation:

Here's a function that will return a table of the inclusive dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fDatesBetween(@startDate Date, @endDate Date)
    RETURNS @tbl TABLE
        (
            a_date      Date
        )
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @thisDt Date
    SET @thisDt = @startDate

    WHILE @thisDt <= @endDate
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT @thisDt
        SET @thisDt = DateAdd(day, 1, @thisDt)
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Now, if you do an outer join to your table from the function results, 
you will have what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DATES.a_date, SampleTable.value1, SampleTable.value2
  FROM dbo.fDatesBetween(@startDate, @endDate) DATES
       LEFT JOIN SampleTable
          ON DATES.a_date = SampleTable.dt
```

That should give you just what you asked for.

Comment: Almost as bad as a recursive CTE.