# Select values that doesn't exist SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table:

Year   Status
2014   OK
2014   OK
2013   OK
2011   OK

I don't have record for 2012 and 2010, and I have 2014 twice.

What I need to do is this return:

Year  Status
2014  OK
2014  OK
2013  OK
2012  NOK
2011  OK
2010  NOK

I saw [How to Select records that don't exist in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691426/how-to-select-records-that-dont-exist-in-sql-server), but I don't understand how to do it...

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Left-Join` with a sequence, for example:

```
WITH Years 
     AS (SELECT TOP ((SELECT Max(YEAR)FROM STATUS) - (SELECT Min(YEAR)FROM 
        STATUS) + 1) 
        Year = (SELECT Min(YEAR) 
        FROM   STATUS) 
        + Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [OBJECT_ID]) 
         FROM   sys.ALL_OBJECTS) 
SELECT y.YEAR, 
       Status = CASE 
                  WHEN s.STATUS IS NULL THEN 'NOK' 
                  ELSE s.STATUS 
                END 
FROM   Years y 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN STATUS s 
                    ON y.YEAR = s.YEAR 
ORDER  BY y.YEAR
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a228b/12/0)</kbd>

Read: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: You have 150,000 reputation and you're not even bothering to check to see if basic questions like this have a duplicate?

Comment: @KyleHale: if it's a duplicate vote to close. My reputation does not necessarily  mean that i'm a sql-crack and i was interested in this approach since i haven't used it this way before.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I think it will help me!
@KyleHale, I'm so sorry, I know that it is duplicated, but as I told, I didnt't understand how it works...

Comment: I don't expect you to be a SQL-crack, I do kind of expect you to be a good steward of SO.

Comment: This answer is a lot clearer than anything suggested in the supposed "duplicate."

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT
   t1.year,
   isnull(t2.status, 'NOK') status
FROM
   (
      SELECT 2014 year UNION ALL
      SELECT 2013 year UNION ALL
      SELECT 2012 year UNION ALL
      SELECT 2011 year UNION ALL
      SELECT 2010 year
   ) t1

   LEFT JOIN my_year_table t2 on
      t2.year = t1.year
```

Comment: Need a bit more insight into your problem. Not sure if that is the best way for you to be creating your years

Comment: @user2046486 for this approach if you need to generate years dynamically, then take a look at this link: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: Ryan-Neal Mes, my years came from the table, we look 10 years back. 
I changed your statement to adapt to my table, and instead of bringing all the years, it brings me 2013 and 2012 (2012 I have 2 distinct records).
Any idea?