# Query to create records that don't exist between 2 points

Tags: mysql, sql

I've currently written a query that returns the following

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| client_id | Period | Status |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|      2378 |      1 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      2 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      4 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      5 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      6 | Frozen |
|      2378 |     10 | Paid   |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

However I would like it to include the periods for where I don't have any data.
Eg Period 3 and periods 7-9. By filling in what occurred in the previous period.
For example Period 3 would become paid. Like so:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| client_id | Period | Status |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|      2378 |      1 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      2 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      3 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      4 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      5 | Paid   |
|      2378 |      6 | Frozen |
|      2378 |      7 | Frozen |
|      2378 |      8 | Frozen |
|      2378 |      9 | Frozen |
|      2378 |     10 | Paid   |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Note that I do have more than 1 client ID present, and my intention is just to complete any blanks between the Minimum and Maximum Period that I have present for that Client_Id in the data. 
Also the periods for each client varies from client to client. For example Client 1 can have a Max period 6 and Client 2 a Max period of 8.

Does anyone know of a way that this can be done?

I came across the following question which is slightly similar except for my case I feel like I need to code a loop over the different client_id's?
[Example I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691426/how-to-select-records-that-dont-exist-in-sql-server)

Comment: maybe if you can `CREATE TEMP TABLES` and build a table with all possible periods, and then do some Kind of smart `JOIN` or `UNION` stuff. but Sound difficult to me

Answer (score 2):

A typical solution is to define a source (table) with all periods and left join your query to the table.

```
select
   ap.Period,
   case when q.Status is not null then q.Status else @prevStatus end as status,
   @prevStatus:=q.Status
from all_periods ap 
     left join (your query here) q on ap.Period = q.Period,
     (select @prevStatus:='undefined') sess
```

Comment: this wont put the value of the previous row as Status for unknown periods, though

Comment: @RealCheeseLord I updated the answer. Don't know where to get status if 1 period is missing though